# Typescript: Arrow function - TS2339: Property does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular, I often get `typescript` compile errors when using `fat arrow functions` inside an `rxjs` stream.

I can still run the app and it does transpile, but I would like to know how to get rid of the error and understand it.

Given:

```
this.data$ = this.route.params
        .switchMap(params =>  
             Observable.forkJoin([
                 Observable.of(params),
                 this.http.get('/api', { param1: params.param1, param2: params.param2 })
        ])
        //**Errors from this part below**
        .map(([params, data]) => data.prop1 + ' - ' + params.param1)
```

I get the errors:

> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   file.ts:xx:xx 
>       TS2339: Property 'prop1' does not exist on type '{}'.
>
> ERROR in [at-loader]
>   file.ts:xx:xx 
>       TS2339: Property 'param1' does not exist on type '{}'.

Why does it complain about this?

Comment: Typescript thinks that the route params from angular are an empty object and should not have any attributes. Just typecast params to `any` and the errors should be gone

Comment: so you mean use "data.prop1 as any"? Not sure how the syntax would look, if you can please answer with syntax?

Comment: That depends on the data u are getting from your api. does your api has a data with prop1?

Comment: @Smit, yes it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
this.data$ = this.route.params
    .switchMap((params: any) =>  
         Observable.forkJoin([
             Observable.of(params),
             this.http.get('/api', { param1: params.param1, param2: params.param2 })
    ])
    //**Errors from this part below**
    .map(([params, data]: [any, any]) => data.prop1 + ' - ' + params.param1)
```

Comment: I also got rid of error like this: [params, data]: any[] , thank-you